# Scala Function Chain and Types

Tags: function, scala, chain

```
def t[A] = (l:Seq[A]) => l tail
def r[A] = (r:Seq[A]) => r reverse

(Function.chain(List(r[Int], t[Int])))(List(1,2,3,4))
```

> List(3, 2, 1)

as expected. However, how can I generalize the types? If I say:

```
(Function.chain(List(r[A], t[A])))(List(1,2,3,4))
```

or
    (Function.chain(List(r, t)))(List(1,2,3,4))

In the first I get type A not found, and the second type mismatch; found :Int(1) required :Nothing

Obviously missing something, but I do not understand the type syntax in this case.

Comment: You probably want something like `def rThenT[A] = Function.chain(List(r[A], t[A]))`, but it isn't really clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is probably the best I can do?  I was trying to introduce the type 'A' to (Function.chain(List(r[A], t[A]))) and do not know how to do this, without defining a function

Comment: Anonymous functions can't take type parameters, only methods. There is really no way to get around needing to use `def`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `t` and `r` to work on sequences of any type, you could do this:

```
def t = (l: Seq[Any]) => l.tail
def r = (l: Seq[Any]) => l.reverse

(Function.chain(List(r, t)))(List(1, 2, "three", 4, 5))
```